# AndEngine player, background and camera

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm developing a 2D shooter using AndEngine. At the moment I'm trying to make the camera follow the player. As I've understood the common approach is to use the `SmoothCamera` zooming it and setting the chased entity. The problem is that the camera follows the player WITH background moving also (`RepeatingSpriteBackground`), so it looks like the player doesn't move at all though the actual position changes. So I don't really get how to make the camera follow the player and have the background not moving. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest approach would be to put the player sprite in a container at center of the container (X:0, y:0), and if he gets some speed, move him away from the center on distance equal to his speed. For example if you move right, you would first gain vx = 0.1 and move him to x:0.1 in the container, then vx = 2 and his distance would be 2 pixels on right from center of the container, and in the end when he's running vx = 10, he would be 10 pixels away from center. If the player character changes his speed smoothly, this will grant you a smooth camera follow effect.

You could multiply velocities by a constant value to make the effect stronger.